# MonoTouch.Dialog with custom base UIViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I have a requirement to have all controllers inherit from a single base controller. However, some controllers use MonoTouch.Dialog, which requires the DialogViewController.

Is it possible to create a UIViewController, and internally, create a DialogViewController and replace (or AddSubView) the UIViewController's view with the one created from the DialogViewController?

What about rotations? memory warnings? etc? Is this recommended? Is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIViewController containment.

This is a new feature on iOS 6:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/

Comment: That is what I did. Had to add custom code to detected when "this" was popped so that I could call RemoveFromParentViewController because the GC never collected the controller otherwise.

Comment: Also, isn't this feature in iOS 5?